# It's possible to publish a specific package with Lerna?

Tags: lerna

I have a mono-repository and need to publish a single package.

Example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDD0h.png)

How can I do this, using Lerna?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible using lerna, as stated in https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/1055

> As I noted above, this is impossible due to the manner in which lerna coordinates versions with git tags (and the diff since the last one is what indicates which packages should be published).

> If they are both independent, and you don’t want to publish them at the same time, then don’t use lerna, it’s clearly not necessary for your use case.

That said you can always use `npm publish` to publish any single package.

Answer (score 0):

## Workaround

in the project that you need to skip publishing, open its package.json and add `private: true`

then in `lerna.json`

```
version: {
 private: false
}
```